# Django view not returning HttpResponse Object

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

Trying to pass a user form for registration, however the view is not returning the user_form object.

**view**

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
            new_user.save()
            return render(request, 'account/register.html', {'new_user':new_user})
    else:
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'account/register.html', {'user_form', user_form})
```

**template**

```
{% block title%}Create an Account{% endblock %}

{%block content%}
    <h1>Create an Account</h1>
    <p>Please, sign up using the following form</p>
    <form method="post">
        {{user_form.as_p}}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p><input type="submit" value="Create my account"><p/>
    </form>
{%endblock%}
```

**url**

`path('register/',views.register, name='register')`

**error**

`The view account.views.register didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`

Comment: Your view looks fine, have you debugged to make sure that your view is being called and it gets to the render calls? Where is the `render` function defined/imported?

Comment: @IainShelvington using `from django.shortcuts import render`, using `path('register/',views.register, name='register')` to link the view to the template.

Comment: first, try to put in the `action` for `form` attribute even if it is empty  and keep `csrf_token` before rendering the form